# create table based on two different sql server

Tags: sql-server

i have two server that in each server i have a sql database. assume that server1 and server2.
now i want to create a query that copy a table from server1 and put it in server2.
i dont want to export that table and import it in the other server because the table in server1 is being updated daily and i want that update come automatically in server2.
what is the solution?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?`

Comment: sql server on both servers

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options. For advanced scenarios you can use [SQL Server Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication?view=sql-server-ver16).

I think the simplest solution is:

- Create a linked server SERVER2 on SERVER1
- Create a trigger on the table on server1
- Inside the trigger, repeat the action on the table at the linked server